# ADD GeoJson with real-time update functionality (no tracking)

Tags: android, google-maps, real-time, geojson

I'm trying to apply the example below for my own App. To Add a Geojson file I've managed with another code but I couldn't make it to work with real time data. I Just want to show different colors depending on the condition of the point To Accepts real-time information.  The First problem with the code is that it does not run the example, has many bugs. The second attempt to bring it to the measure of my app shows some extra errors.  One of the faults is the getmap() which has been replaced by the getmapAync but It didn't fix the problem .
Any Suggestions for code errors. Is any better way to add real time spatial  data, no tracking info just status from their properties.

[GeoJSON — displays and styles GeoJSON data](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils)

```
package com.example.testnavbar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.google.maps.android.data.Feature;
import com.google.maps.android.data.geojson.GeoJsonFeature;
import com.google.maps.android.data.geojson.GeoJsonLayer;
import com.google.maps.android.data.geojson.GeoJsonLineString;
import com.google.maps.android.data.geojson.GeoJsonPointStyle;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox.getApplicationContext;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private final static String mLogTag = "GeoJson";

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    MapView mMapView;
    View mView;

    /**
     * Assigns a color based on the given magnitude
     */
    private static float magnitudeToColor(double status) {
        if (status == 1) {
            return BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN;
        } else if (status == 2) {
            return BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW;
        } else {
            return BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED;
        }
    }

    protected int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.activity_maps;
    }


    protected void startDemo() {
        // Download the GeoJSON file.
        retrieveFileFromUrl();
        // Alternate approach of loading a local GeoJSON file.
        //retrieveFileFromResource();
    }

    private void retrieveFileFromUrl() {
        new DownloadGeoJsonFile().execute(getString(R.string.geojson_url));
    }

    private void retrieveFileFromResource() {
        try {
            GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(getMap(), R.raw.picnicsites, this);
            addGeoJsonLayerToMap(layer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(mLogTag, "GeoJSON file could not be read");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(mLogTag, "GeoJSON file could not be converted to a JSONObject");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds a point style to all features to change the color of the marker based on its magnitude
     * property
     */
    private void addColorsToMarkers(GeoJsonLayer layer) {
        // Iterate over all the features stored in the layer
        for (GeoJsonFeature feature : layer.getFeatures()) {
            // Check if the magnitude property exists
            if (feature.getProperty("mag") != null && feature.hasProperty("place")) {
                double magnitude = Double.parseDouble(feature.getProperty("mag"));

                // Get the icon for the feature
                BitmapDescriptor pointIcon = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(magnitudeToColor(magnitude));

                // Create a new point style
                GeoJsonPointStyle pointStyle = new GeoJsonPointStyle();

                // Set options for the point style
                pointStyle.setIcon(pointIcon);
                pointStyle.setTitle("Magnitude of " + magnitude);
                pointStyle.setSnippet("Earthquake occured " + feature.getProperty("place"));

                // Assign the point style to the feature
                feature.setPointStyle(pointStyle);
            }
        }
    }

    private class DownloadGeoJsonFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, GeoJsonLayer> {

        @Override
        protected GeoJsonLayer doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                // Open a stream from the URL
                InputStream stream = new URL(params[0]).openStream();

                String line;
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Read and save each line of the stream
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Close the stream
                reader.close();
                stream.close();

                return new GeoJsonLayer(getMap(), new JSONObject(result.toString()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(mLogTag, "GeoJSON file could not be read");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(mLogTag, "GeoJSON file could not be converted to a JSONObject");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(GeoJsonLayer layer) {
            if (layer != null) {
                addGeoJsonLayerToMap(layer);
            }
        }

    }


    private void addGeoJsonLayerToMap(GeoJsonLayer layer) {

        addColorsToMarkers(layer);
        layer.addLayerToMap();
        getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(35.126411,33.429859)));
        // Demonstrate receiving features via GeoJsonLayer clicks.
        layer.setOnFeatureClickListener(new GeoJsonLayer.GeoJsonOnFeatureClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFeatureClick(Feature feature) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeFragment.this,
                        "Feature clicked: " + feature.getProperty("title"),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

    }
}
```